# SSH authentication failed

Tags: ssh

I am using this link

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-your-droplet-with-ssh
```

I got this

```
root@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~# ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-L0mlehDNyPEa/agent.18238; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=18239; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 18239;
root@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~# ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
/root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
```

What does this mean?

```
root@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/.ssh# ls
known_hosts

ps aux | grep ssh
root     17889  0.0  0.0  11232   332 ?        Ss   14:04   0:00 ssh-agent -s
root     17983  0.0  0.0  11232   332 ?        Ss   14:07   0:00 ssh-agent -s
root     17988  0.0  0.0  11232   332 ?        Ss   14:07   0:00 ssh-agent bash
root     18032  0.0  0.0  11232   332 ?        Ss   14:10   0:00 ssh-agent
root     18034  0.0  0.0  11232   332 ?        Ss   14:11   0:00 ssh-agent
root     18056  0.0  0.0  11232   328 ?        Ss   14:11   0:00 ssh-agent -s
root     18237  0.0  0.0  11232   332 ?        Ss   14:22   0:00 ssh-agent -s
root     18239  0.0  0.0  11232   332 ?        Ss   14:22   0:00 ssh-agent
root     18405  0.0  0.0  21292   952 pts/2    S+   14:32   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

Inside known_hosts is my pyblic key.
What is wrong?

Comment: `/root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory` You are trying to add a private key to the ssh-agent which does not exist on your filesystem. You also have a lot of ssh-agent processes running which you might want to clean up.

Comment: @MarkoPolo If I add a private key,will this last only for this session or no?

Comment: That is correct, it will only last for your login session. You can however add a script to your `.bash_profile` to autostart ssh-agent and load your private key (assuming it is not password protected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> /root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> What does this mean?

It means exactly what it says. The file does not exists. The tutorial expects you to have such keys somehow. It is discussed in the comments how to create a key (`ssh-keygen`).